# Storing and retrieving contacts in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I've got a contact picker in my app which returns a contact and from that I'm storing several bits of information into sharedPreferences. In the shared preferences I'm using the lookup key to hold the data (as the android docs seem to suggest)

This part all seems fine and I get and store the lookup key.

My problem is then went I come to getting back the contacts looking up the contact via the lookup key sometimes seems to return null

The following details come from the contact picker

```
 Contact lookup key from the contact picker: 850i%2bw7vj56otre6eqa9b9t7wa%3d%3d  
 Contact id: 2958
```

Then I try to lookup the contact based upon the lookup key using the following code to get the contact id:

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, Uri.encode("850i%2bw7vj56otre6eqa9b9t7wa%3d%3d"));
Uri res = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(context.getContentResolver(), lookupUri);
```

After doing this "res" is null even though I know the id is valid as it's come from the contact picker.

Putting in some logging the res uri in the lookup is:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/850i%252bw7vj56otre6eqa9b9t7wa%253d%253d
```

Which (once encoded) is what I thought it should be.
Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

The thing is, it works for most people (myself included) but some people are coming across this.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Use [`Uri.decode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `Uri.encode()`</strike>.

**Edit:**
According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI):

> Lookup key should be appended unencoded - it is stored in the encoded
>   form, ready for use in a URI.

So you should neither encode or decode the URI. Pass it as it is.

Comment: Thanks, I've not had any luck with that either. Should I be encoding when I get the value from the contact picker and then decoding when doing the lookup? It's a tricky one to test as I'm having to do it remotley with a user that has the issue and can't try it easily myself. I've got a test app running with them. If I get them to use the contact picker it then displays the lookup key. If I then iterate through the contacts and get the details for that user by searching via other contact data I can see the same lookup key, the only difference been one is uppercase and the other isn't.

Comment: The reason I suggested using `decode()` is because the key was already URI encoded (judging by the presence of `%`). Further, the `%2b` in the key is `+` in hex; and `%3d` is `=`. Having `==` at the end means that the key itself is base64 encoded (not that it matters). Anyway, if you *again* URI encode the key, the `%` char is itself encoded in its hex form as `%25`, which, I felt is not right. So I suggested to decode instead. Perhaps there's more than one problem.

Comment: Edited the answer with info from documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've tried with no decoding at all but the user still had no success. In the end because the lookup key matched (apart from the case of the string) I've written a fallback routine to do the standard lookup contact method call and if the data isn't found then to query the lookup key field directly with an ignoring case query. It won't be too good if they change the contact data, but it seems to be for only a tiny percentage of contacts for a tiny percentage of users. Thanks for your suggestions. It's still a bit of a mystery to why it doesn't work with the standard call.

Answer (score 1):

As Dheeraj V.S. said, you should not neither encode or decode the lookupkey it is allready encoded so re-encoding it may have strange results. Now I think that your approach creates problems with contacts that have their id changed. If this is the case then you should try to append the contact's last known key in your lookup uri and see what happens.

Something like:

```
Uri lookupUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupkey), contactid);
```

I think that android needs the contactid in order to determine if it has changed although the documentations states that it is optional.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I only added the encode/decode when having problems in the first place, so that's all removed. You can add the contact id, but the whole idea of the lookup key is that it works if data is changed. The contact id will get removed after a factory reset or getting a new phone whereas the lookup id stays the same. Adding the contact id is really just a quicker method for situations where it hasn't changed. In this situation even adding the contact id doesn't work.